# Custom Exception : Checked Vs Unchecked from the performance point of view

Tags: java, exception

i read it somewhere :-
"Don’t' use Exception to control application behavior. Exception handling is very expensive as it requires native calls to copy stack trace, each time exception is created. While creating a custom exception, prefer to create an unchecked, Runtime exception than a checked exception, especially if you know that client is not going to take any reactive action other than logging." 
Is it right?

Comment: Exception handling means dealing with **possible mistakes**.  If you are trying to "use an exception" as yet another way to return an answer (result) from a method body, you have failed.  **Exception's should only be used to indicate that a problem has occurred - and precisely the type of problem that you and your code cannot handle**  Handling an exception means the user of your code has to provide a solution to that problem.  People sometimes act like "Exceptions" are another way to return a result to a user - but that is a mistake.

Comment: There is no performance difference between checked and unchecked exception, if that's what you're asking. Choosing one over the other is a matter of design, not performance.

Comment: It is certain the **opinion** of the authors of _Clean Code_ under the assumption you are not writing an API.

Comment: To continue: a **_regular exception_** indicates that you know what type of problem could occur, and indicates you ought to have the where-with-all to handle it.  A **_Java RuntimeException_** indicates that the problem is something you had no ability to control.  I (**personally**) think the `java.io.IOException` is the classic example of a "Run Time Exception" - specifically an error that was not your fault, nor could you handle in your code - and must be handled by the user of your code.

Comment: Check this for more information about exceptions performance http://java-performance.info/throwing-an-exception-in-java-is-very-slow/
And one more article from a person who develops JDK https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/exceptional-performance/